# count json array controller laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, controller

I am learning **JSON** and I want to show a custom output. The dates are the same, they must be added together.

The data of my database table is as follows:

```
id  no_id   type     created_at
------------------------------------------------
1    1      post     2023-10-11T17:13:19.000000Z
2    85     post     2023-10-11T17:13:19.000000Z
3    23     post     2023-10-12T17:24:33.000000Z
4    40     post     2023-10-12T17:24:33.000000Z
5    87     product  2023-10-12T17:24:33.000000Z
```

Example:

```
2023-10-11 => 2
2023-10-12 => 3
```

My Laravel's controller file is as follows:

```php
class StatController extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $stats = Stat::groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))->get()->toArray();

        return array_reverse($stats);
    }
}
```

The output of the controller code shows as follows (json):

```json
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "no_id": 85,
        "type": "post",
        "created_at": "2023-10-11T17:13:19.000000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "no_id": 87,
        "type": "product",
        "created_at": "2023-10-12T17:24:33.000000Z"
    }
]
```

But I want to show the **JSON** output as follows:

```json
[
    {
        "date": "2023-10-11",
        "totalViews": "2"
    },
    {
        "date": "2023-10-12",
        "totalViews": "3"
    }
]
```

Comment: Related: [Laravel Eloquent get results grouped by days](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20603075/2943403) and [Laravel Group By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26601782/2943403) and [Laravel group by date to month only and get count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32978842/2943403) and [Laravel Eloquent: Count Rows and group them by the day](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51402064/2943403)

Comment: This looks like an identical question: [Laravel query builder count rows by day SQL db::raw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67785419/2943403) as well as [Daily post count out of a timestamp column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21071453/2943403)

Comment: And this also looks related: [laravel count records based on each single date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63032050/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try groupBy `created_at` and count each group like this:

```
$stats = Stat::selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at,"%Y-%m-%d") as date, COUNT(*) as totalViews')
   ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
   ->get()
   ->toArray();
```